# How to show data in tableview using Alamofire and swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I got the following response array of values:

```
["Mallard Point Trailer Court","Golddust","Hagler","McCosh Mill","Graystone","Old Jonesboro","Carlees Mobile Home Court","Denson","Blake","Inverness Cliffs"]
```

How to load this data in my tableview by using alamofire?

Here is my code

```
 let url = Constants.CityUrl + fullName
            print(url)
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                    let response = JSON as! NSArray
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating tableview cells from JSON with Alamofire (Swift 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506139/populating-tableview-cells-from-json-with-alamofire-swift-2)

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to access the array in whole class you need to declare it global like below, also prefer swift "Array" over "NSArray", As it has many advantages

```
var reponseArray = [String]
```

Also call below method from `viewDidLoad`

```
func fetchInformation() {
let url = Constants.CityUrl + fullName
            print(url)
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                    reponseArray = JSON as! Array

         DispatchQueue.main.async {  
             tableView.reloadData()
            //reload on main thread
           }
     }
}
```

In Table View Data source method use information from `reponseArray`

Answer (score 0):

Add one variable outside the completion block and assign the response to it.
For example:

```
let arrResponse: [String]?
```

In tableView delegate methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrResponse.count
    }



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
             var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = arrResponse[indexPath.row] as! String

        return cell
        }
```

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, Updated answer.

Comment: Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in from this line itself i git the error

Comment: i got the problem how to call the request by suing array of values

Comment: @Agaram I don't get what you say?

Comment: ["Mallard Point Trailer Court","Golddust","Hagler","McCosh Mill","Graystone","Old Jonesboro","Carlees Mobile Home Court","Denson","Blake","Inverness Cliffs"] this is reponse ..just tell me how to get the request by using alomofire